# Impact on Android Apps switching from 1024 bit to 2048 bit SSL

Tags: android, ssl

I currently have an Android App leveraging a Popular weservice that currently uses 1024 bit SSL certs. I was notified that the webservice will be migrating to 2048 bit SSL certs. I was wondering :

- How will this impact the users using my app on an older version of Android (ex: 1.x)?
- I am assuming that my current code using HttpsURLConnection will take care of the change automatically, am I right in thinking so??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How will this impact the users using my app on an older version of Android (ex: 1.x)?

It's not a real answer, just a thought. (I am not aware whether 1.x had limitation ok RSA key length supported).

Based on [Usage share](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29#Usage_share) article, there is about 0.6% of users who still uses Android 1.x. I would say it makes sense to concentrate on so small percentage, only if you have have absolutely huge user base.

> I am assuming that my current code using HttpsURLConnection will take care of the change >automatically, am i right in thinking so??

Yes. You don't need to do anything.